# Sample from groups proportional to score

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, google-bigquery, sampling

I have data with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS scores (
  id int,
  class char,
  score float
);

INSERT INTO scores VALUES
(1, 'A', 0.5),
(1, 'B', 0.2),
(1, 'C', 0.1),
(2, 'A', 0.1),
(2, 'B', 0.2),
(3, 'D', 0.01),
(4, 'A', 0.5),
(4, 'B', 0.5);
```

I want to randomly sample, for each id, a class. A possible sample obtained would be:

```
1,'A'
2,'B'
3,'D'
4,'A'
```

The logic I want to use for the sample is the following: each class is sampled proportionally to its score. For instance:

- In `id = 1`, sampling class 'B' should be twice as likely to be sampled than class 'C'.
- In `id = 2`, sampling class 'B' should be twice as likely to be sampled than class 'A'.
- In `id = 3`, we should only sample class 'D'.
- In `id = 4`, sampling class 'B' should be as likely as sampling class 'A'.

I'm looking for ways of doing this in BigQuery/PostgreSQL. Also, are there solutions with a fixed random seed that can be reproduced?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible approach is to generate for each 'id-class' pair a number of rows equivalent to the score (50 '1-A' rows, 20 '1-B' rows, 10 '1-C' rows, etc...) and then select 1 row randomly per id.

For BigQuery:

```
select id, array_agg(class order by rand() limit 1)[offset(0)]
from scores, unnest(generate_array(1, score * 100))
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have a column that essentially has weights.  You want to use these for random sampling, to extract one row for each `id` but the likelihood of that row is based on the weight.

The idea is to do the following:

- Normalize the weights to be a range between 0 and 1.  You do this by using a cumulative sum and division.
- Choose one random number per `id`.
- Compare the two.

The logic looks like this:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, 
             sum(score) over (partition by id order by class) / sum(score) over (partition by id) as threshold_hi,
             (sum(score) over (partition by id order by class) - score) / sum(score) over (partition by id) as threshold_lo
      from scores s
     ) s join
     (select i.id, random() as rand
      from (select distinct id from scores) i
     ) i
     on i.id = s.id and
        i.rand >= s.threshold_lo and i.rand < s.threshold_hi
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f04f4454fb0120e707959a8861fdb613) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

In `PostgreSQL` i know for 2 ways.

**1st Way** with `DISTINCT` and `RANDOM()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, class
FROM scores 
ORDER BY id, random();
```

**2nd Way** with `OVER PARTITION BY` and `RANDOM()`:

```
SELECT id, class 
FROM (
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY random()) as rn
FROM scores ) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Both queries you can check on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=44299bebfb342649374e67bbcffffa63)

Pay attention that if you ran both queries at same time that you will get different records.